# Read Path From A Function In Laravel VueJS Inertia Path Writing

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite, inertiajs

I have a file named ***Test.vue*** and inside this file I have an `img` tag:

```
<img src="../../img/map.jpg" alt="Map" />
```

This works fine and after running `npm run build` everything will be generated successfully and image will be displayed.

Now, I want to get rid of those `../` in my path because first of all it looks ugly and second of all sometimes in some other files I even have to provide many more `../` in my path and of course it gets even more ugly.

The Problem is, as soon as we try to use a method or anything else inside our `src` attribute, it's not going to work anymore

```
<img :src="someMethod('map.jpg')" alt="Map" />
// someMethod('map.jpg') returns exactly the same string : '../../img/map.jpg'
```

In this case browser displays a 404 not found error in console and it's looking for `'localhost:8000/img/map.jpg'` (`localhost:8000` is my root address) and of course the path is wrong and there is no image in this path.

In order to understand the problem better, take a look at following examples :

```
<img src="../../img/map.jpg" alt="Map" /> // Works fine 
<img :src="'../../img/map.jpg'" alt="Map" /> // Doesn't Work
```

So, The conclusion is if you write your path without attribute binding it works, and as soon  as you use `:src` instead of `src` it's not gonna work.

**My question is, how can I read paths from a function and compile it successfully?**

I am using default configs for Laravel Projects using Inertia, VueJS & Vite.
Here is my scripts section in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build && vite build --ssr && vite build && vite build --ssr --ssr"
},
```

By the way, this is my folder structure, if you like to know:

```
resources
|____ img
|     |____ map.jpg
|____ js
|      |____ Pages
|            |_____ Test.vue
|
|____ css // its content (not important in this example)
|____ views  // its content (not important in this example)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to bind a relative image path with Vite

```js
function someMethod(name) {
  return new URL(`../assets/${name}`, import.meta.url).href
}
```

[Vite documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets#new-url-url-import-meta-url)

Alternatively, use absolute path

```js
function someMethod(name) {
  return `src/assets/${name}`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use '@' to import resource ,like src="@/img/map.jpg",you just need add a property in your vite.config.js

```js
resolve: 
 alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    },
  },
```